# SVN Pre Commit check

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We have two branches A and B with the same source code structure

Any check in that happens in B , need to happen in A as well.

For example : 
There is a file Employee.java in branch A and branch B in the below folder
*project/src/main/java/com/mycomp/Employee.java*

While checking in the file Employee.java to branch B , I need to check if the same file is already checked into branch A by comparing the contents of Employee.java in both the branches . If not , I should not allow the developer to commit

Is it possible to implement such logic in SVN pre commit hook and fail the commit ? 
Is there any out of the box solution from SVN to implement such checks ?

Comment: What kind of check?

Comment: elaborated the details of the check in the question

Comment: Why do you think such blocking is useful? What kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Well, while I find the use case rather strange, it can be achieved with SVN pre commit hooks (some scripting required).

Here is a decent write up of how to create and use pre commit hooks:

http://wordaligned.org/articles/a-subversion-pre-commit-hook